# Temos alguma tag para indicar questões sobre operações binárias?

Tags: debate, tags, tags-sinônimas

Se temos alguma pergunta sobre operações bit a bit, representação binária, etc, seria interessante indicarmos com alguma tag própria para isso.

Avaliando as tags existentes encontrei:

- [bit](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bit), com 18 perguntas
- [bits](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bits), com 4 perguntas
- [binary](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/binary), com 45 perguntas
- [números-binários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/n%c3%bameros-bin%c3%a1rios), com 12 perguntas

Parece que hoje não há definido qual é a tag que realmente deveria ser utilizada.

Como podemos resolver isso? As quatro são sinônimos? Se sim, qual poderíamos manter e adicionar as outras como sinônimas?

Comment: Tinha que ter 2 opções

Comment: @Maniero Quais? Uma para representação e outra para operações?

Comment: Sei lá, só sei que deveria ter duas :D

Comment: Sou leigo demais com termos, muita coisa entendo na prática, então lhes pergunto [tag:lógica-binária] (ou [tag:operação-binária]) comportaria tudo isto? (ps: nenhuma das tags existentes me fazem sentir familiaridade, posso estar enganado também)

Comment: Talvez as 3 primeiras sejam de fato sinônimas. Números binários, entretanto, tenho ressalvas. Talvez a informação esteja simplesmente representada em binário, mas sem usá-la como um número...

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Talvez ter como o Bruno citou? `operação-binária` e `representação-binária`?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, não vejo lógica binária como sinônimo ou substituto para um "binário" de bits e bytes. Também pode-se haver algo sobre binários que não envolva operação

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, acho que por aí. Mas podemos por uma terceira opção e mudar de "binário" pra "nebuloso" e ficarmos todos confusos =D

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, as primeiras questões listadas dessas 3 primeiras tags são muito ruins. Inclusive tem uma de "bits" que nem trata de bits, mas de caracteres (pelo menos a primeira vista)

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Sim, foi isso que me alertou que essas tags estão uma bagunça.

Comment: E "binary"? Por que diabos tá numa pergunta sobre busca/ordenação? Tá bem avacalhada a coisa... Lembra-me o uso da tag "uri" para questões do URI-Judge, nada a ver com URI